# Tweaking an old post's code

Tags: vba, excel

I like this old code to help me find words:

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim oRange As Range, aCell As Range, bCell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim SearchString As String, FoundAt As String

    On Error GoTo Err

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set oRange = ws.Columns(1)

    SearchString = "Mike"

    Set aCell = oRange.Find(What:=SearchString, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        Set bCell = aCell

        If InStr(1, aCell.Value, "Anderson", vbTextCompare) Then _
        FoundAt = aCell.Address

        Do
            Set aCell = oRange.FindNext(After:=aCell)

            If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do
                If InStr(1, aCell.Value, "Anderson", vbTextCompare) Then _
                FoundAt = FoundAt & ", " & aCell.Address
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    Else
        MsgBox SearchString & " not Found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    MsgBox "The Search String has been found these locations: " & FoundAt
    Exit Sub
    Err:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

could i add more names to :
SearchString = "Mike" <-- Like " "Mike" "Andrea" "Etc"

Comment: Yes. Should I ask a new question and re word it?

Answer (score 0):

or you could use AutoFilter

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim aCell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1W")

    Dim searchArray As Variant
    searchArray = Array("Mike", "Andrea", "Mary") '<--| list your names to search for

    With ws '<--| reference relevant sheet
        With .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its column A cells from row 1 (header) down to last not empty one
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=searchArray, Operator:=xlFilterValues '<--| filter it with 'searchArray' array values
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then '<--| if any filtered cells other then headers
                With .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                    MsgBox "Names: " & vbCrLf & Join(searchArray, ";") & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "found in cells " & vbCrLf & .Address
                    For Each aCell In .Cells '<--| loop through your matching cells

                        'your code to handle current matching cell

                    Next
                End With
            End If
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @VBABeginner, did you get through it?